# Core Data Migration error message "'Model does not contain configuration 'XYZ'.'"

Tags: cocoa, core-data, macos

I have a Managed Object Context to which I add two different SQLite stores. I use Configurations in the Mananged Object Model to assign certain entities to one store and other entities to the other. The Configurations are called "UserDB" and "MainDB".

Everything works okay until I try to use automatic migration. After creating a new Managed Object Model version, and adding a new attribute to one of the entities in the UserDB Configuration, I get an exception when adding the old version store (for the UserDB related store) to the store coordinator: 'Model does not contain configuration 'UserDB'.'  I can find no hits for this error on Google. Anyone out there using multiple stores with Configurations? Anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong?

The stack looks like this:

```
objc_exception_throw
-[NSManagedObjectModel isConfiguration:compatibleWithStoreMetadata:]
-[NSStoreMigrationPolicy sourceModelForStoreAtURL:metadata:error:]
-[NSStoreMigrationPolicy(InternalMethods) _gatherDataAndPerformMigration:]
-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:]
-[MyAppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]
```

Comment: Ran into this problem as well. Does the same thing happen when creating migration maps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a bug with migration+configurations. I was able to work around the problem by going through the same motions and passing nil for configuration when calling addPersistentStoreWithType. The migration happens, and then I can make a new persistent store coordinator and add the stores again with the proper Configuration string arguments.

This is the second configuration related bug I've run into. Not a well tested feature apparently.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. This was indeed my problem as well.

Comment: Hmm been wrestling with this the past day or so. This solution "almost" works. But it looks like there is a timing issue attached to it: i.e. it only works sometimes if I pause execution long enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The fact pattern was identical and the error message the same. It turned out, however, to be the result of my own mistake.

Let's say the old model was Blah.xcdatamodel and the new Blah 2.xcdatamodel. I had started making changes to Blah before realising my mistake and creating Blah 2. I then used my version control system (Git) to revert to the old Blah and then recreated Blah 2. Everything looked right. But I must have done something wrong in the reversion process, because when I thought to double check that Blah.xcdatamodel in my current project folder was really the same as Blah.xcdatamodel in the project folder I used to build the previous version of the app (fortunately I always keep a zipped archive of the project folder for each released version as I don't fully trust version control systems), I found that they were in fact different, albeit that they looked identical in XCode. The file size was different, for instance.

I substituted the old Blah into my current project folder, and lo and behold it all went perfectly, without any need for the workaround described by Ken.

I am not saying that Ken had necessarily made a similar mistake, but if you do encounter this message it is at least worth confirming that the model you are migrating from is REALLY the model that was used to create the data in question.

Comment: I have since found that the problem was in fact NOT solved. It seems that it worked the second time only because the data had in fact been migrated the first time. In other words, the first time you run it the data is migrated but the app fails with the "Model does not contain configuration 'XYZ" message. Then the second time it runs fine. This is of course not a great user experience, so I was forced to adopt a 2-stage approach like Ken's.

Comment: Furthermore, this two stage approach has its own problem, at least for me, namely a crash the first (and only the first) time a user switches to another app after migrating the data. I will put this in a separate question.